# Distribution-free prediction intervals in linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval, resampling

I've found some literature on the subject, but it is rather difficult to read. I am wondering if the following simplified method makes sense. My question is what part is correct in this methodology, and what is wrong.

The model is $Y=P+\epsilon=X\beta+\epsilon$ where $P=X\beta$ is the vector of predicted values ($X$ represents the independent variables, also called features), $Y$ is the observed response vector, and $\epsilon$ the residual error vector. Here $\beta$ is the estimated regression coefficient vector. That is, $\beta=\arg\min_{\beta_*}||Y-X\beta_*||$.

Now, randomly reshuffle the entries of $\epsilon$. You get a new vector denoted as $\epsilon'$. In short, you are doing resampling. Define $Y'=Y-\epsilon+\epsilon'$. Find $\beta'$ the new regression coefficient vector minimizing $||Y'-X\beta'||$. That is, $\beta'=\arg\min_{\beta_*}||Y'-X\beta_*||$.

At this point you have two regression coefficient vectors $\beta,\beta'$. Reshuffle $\epsilon$ a hundred times to get $\epsilon', \epsilon'', \epsilon'''$ and so on, leading to a hundred regression coefficient vector $\beta',\beta'',\beta'''$ and so on.

Look at the empirical distribution of $\beta',\beta'',\dots$ to get model-free confidence intervals for the regression coefficients. Likewise, given $x$, a location in the feature space,
compute the $100$ predicted values for $x$, using $\beta',\beta''$ and so on. This will lead to your prediction interval for the predicted value computed at location $x$ in the feature space.

I am wondering, in particular, if this technique produces prediction intervals that are too small, or biased in some way.

Comment: One direction forward might be to explore what "model-free" might actually mean.  You are implicitly assuming the errors are *iid,* for instance: otherwise, this permutation distribution would be invalid.  You also are describing a procedure that cannot possibly be carried out, because it requires knowing the values of the errors $\epsilon,$ and your language confounds *models* with *estimates.*  But if we understand you to be talking about the *model residuals* instead of the errors, this makes sense. Am I reading your intentions correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's model residuals, which are known for the training set. Must be iid, yes. I have a different version for time series violating iid; here I discuss the most basic example. I also assume large values of $Y$ are not associated with large values of $\epsilon$ and conversely, otherwise it needs to be addressed too.